# How can I create an image with a rounded rectangle for a border

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create this view, like the image below:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tiledefault"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="HELLO"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frame"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/frame"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/frame" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am stuck here. No idea how to make that border rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create drawable file border.xml

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="@dimen/dp1" android:color="@color/colorLightGray"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/dp8"/>
</shape>
```

Then add background for constraintlayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: Would a cardview be better for this?

Comment: depend your design , but cardview can not create border

Answer (score 0):

`ShapeOfView` disable the **background** property of your view

use this library :

```
implementation 'com.github.florent37:shapeofview:1.3.2'
```

this library is very good for shape image and layout